# Why is Image Mosaic in ArcMap showing triangle

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, mosaic

When I mosaic two rasters in ArcMap 10.2 using [Mosaic (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000097000000) tool they give the image shown below.

[image: two AOIs are mosaicked together but they show a triangle]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Two settings of that tool could cause the output you're seeing (alone or in combination). Per the help file now linked in your question:

> For file-based rasters and personal geodatabase rasters, the Ignore
>   Background Value must be set to the same value as NoData in order for
>   the background value to be ignored. File geodatabase rasters and
>   ArcSDE rasters will work without this extra step.

The other setting is the mosaic type. If set to FIRST or LAST, the order the rasters are loaded will determine which one is 'on top'. If set to SUM or another math related method and there is nodata in the cells from either raster, the output would then be nodata.

You don't specify the format of your input rasters, nor the settings you are using in the tool, but my guess would be you need to specify both the nodata value parameter (possibly 0, possibly some large negative number - you'll have to check your data) and also the background value parameter to the same value. From there, the mosaic choice would be based on what you want to happen if a non-nodata in one raster overlaps a non-nodata cell in the other (add them, take the average, take the first, etc.).